# Remove Cell Content if "0"

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to make a spreadsheet with a lot of data and with numerous (11) tabs with the same concept for different people, etc.

However, I do not want a cell to contain "0" if there is nothing to show. I have tried using =IF but I am 99.99% sure I am doing it wrong, which makes it not work... Ive attached a photo showing what I have. Simply I need the sum of cells B6:K6 in P6, and down the line, etc.

Also, since I have 11 tabs with roughly the same concept, I can certainly tell it is slowing down greatly. Any advice or would Google Sheets maybe be better suited?

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: It's a little messy, and I'd like to see a more elegant solution, but `=IF(SUM(B6:K6)=0,"",SUM(B6:K6))` should work.

Comment: Thank you! Now I just need to figure out a way to make it run a little quicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of methods:

```
=IF(SUM(B6,K6)=0,"",SUM(B6,K6))
```

Or you can use a custom format on the cells like:

```
0.00;-0.00;
```

The third spot after the second `;` tells excel how to show `0`.  In this case it will show nothing.

Comment: Never would have thought of the second option, both of them worked great! Thank you

Comment: Leave out the quotes and the IF leaves a blank value.  Otherwise it leaves a string:  `=IF(SUM(B6,K6)=0, ,SUM(B6,K6))`  It will save you later.

Comment: If you do that it will return `TRUE` or `0` and not nothing @Karl_S

Comment: My experience is that an ISBLANK() works with no value on an IF() where it does not and you are testing for a string in formulas referencing the cell otherwise.

Comment: @Karl_S put `=IF(1=1,,2)` in a cell, it will return `0` and not a blank cell.  ISBLANK will not work on any cell that has a formula regardless of what it returns.   It sees the formula and not the returned value.

Comment: Sorry, there are 2 tags here, Google Sheets and Excel.  I believe @ScottCraner is refering to Excel while I am refering to Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do something like `=IF(A1+B1=0,"",A1+B1)`

Or you can uncheck the Show a zero in cells that have zero value option under Display options for this worksheet.

Comment: Where are the Display Options found?  I was unaware of this.

Comment: Well that was a lot easier than I thought. Never knew that existed. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottCraner Me either, I found it under general settings then Advanced =>  then about 2/3 down. "Display options for this worksheet". Third option from the bottom